# Given an specific directory get how many occurences of an specific string appear in every file in bash

Tags: linux, bash

Given a directory get al the txt files and get how many occurences of a string are in every text file using find and grep.

```
find $1 -type f -name "*."$2"" -exec grep $3 -l printf {} \;
```

Being a $1 a directory $2 the txt format and $3 the string to find occurences.

The output must be:

```
$1/file1.txt
3
$1/file2.txt
6
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As `grep -c` counts the matched lines, not the occurences of a string, `grep -o word | wc -l` will be better. Would you please try:

```
find "$1" -type f -name "*.$2" -exec grep -l "$3" "{}" \; -exec bash -c 'grep -o '"$3"' "{}" | wc -l' \;
```

Answer (score 0):

Suggesting feed `find` results into `grep` command. Than format the results with `awk`

```
 grep -c "$3" $(find "$1" -name "*.$2") | awk '{print $1,$2}' FS=":" OFS="\\n"
```